# Carousel in react

Tags: css, image, react.js, jsx

I implemented this carousel component in react:

```
import React from "react";
import { AiOutlineArrowLeft, AiOutlineArrowRight } from "react-icons/ai";
import { useResizeDetector } from "react-resize-detector";

let arrowStyle = {
  background: "white",
  border: "1px solid lightgray",
  borderRadius: "20%",
  cursor: "pointer",
  display: "flex",
  justifyContent: "center",
  alignItems: "center",
  height: 30,
  width: 30,
  boxShadow: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px",
};

export default function Carousel(props) {
  let [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  let innerContainer = React.useRef();
  
  // We use these coordinates to know if we should show left/right arrows or not
  let [relativeCords, setRelativeCords] = React.useState({});
  
  // We use this variable because during transition if user clicks multiple times the arrow buttons, coordinates are not computed correctly anymore
  let [transitionBlock, setTransitionBlock] = React.useState(false);

  let innerContainerRelativeCordsToParent = () => {
    let relativeLeft =
      innerContainer.current.getBoundingClientRect().left -
      ref.current.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    let relativeRight =
      ref.current.getBoundingClientRect().right -
      innerContainer.current.getBoundingClientRect().right;

    setRelativeCords({ relativeLeft, relativeRight });
  };

  const onResize = React.useCallback(() => {
    // When main container is resized we want to update relative coordinates
    innerContainerRelativeCordsToParent();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  const { ref } = useResizeDetector({ onResize });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    innerContainerRelativeCordsToParent();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // We need to run this also when transition ends to get fresh coordinates
    innerContainer.current.addEventListener("transitionend", () => {
      innerContainerRelativeCordsToParent();
      setTransitionBlock(false);
    });
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="carousel" style={{ padding: 50 }}>
      <div
        style={{
          paddingLeft: 50,
          position: "relative",
          paddingRight: 50,
        }}
      >
        <div
          ref={ref}
          style={{
            overflow: "hidden",
          }}
        >
          {/* If you have height issues with below div, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27536428/inline-block-element-height-issue */}
          <div
            ref={innerContainer}
            style={{
              display: "inline-block",
              whiteSpace: "nowrap",
              transition: "transform 0.4s linear",
              transform: `translateX(${-count * 100}px)`,
            }}
          >
            {props.items.map((x) => {
              return (
                <div
                  key={x.id}
                  style={{
                    padding: 5,
                    display: "inline-block",
                    width: 150,
                    height: 150,
                    marginLeft: 5,
                    marginRight: 5,
                    border: "1px solid lightgray",
                    borderRadius: 10,
                    overflow: "auto",
                    whiteSpace: "normal",
                  }}
                >
                  <h1>{x.title}</h1>
                  <p>{x.body}</p>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
        <button
          style={{
            ...arrowStyle,
            position: "absolute",
            left: 0,
            top: "50%",
            transform: "translateY(-50%)",
          }}
          disabled={relativeCords.relativeLeft >= 0}
          onClick={() => {
            if (transitionBlock) return;
            setCount(count - 1);
            setTransitionBlock(true);
          }}
        >
          <AiOutlineArrowLeft />
        </button>
        <button
          style={{
            ...arrowStyle,
            position: "absolute",
            right: 0,
            top: "50%",
            transform: "translateY(-50%)",
          }}
          disabled={relativeCords.relativeRight >= 0}
          onClick={() => {
            if (transitionBlock) return;
            setCount(count + 1);
            setTransitionBlock(true);
          }}
        >
          <AiOutlineArrowRight />
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Any feedback welcome. Here is demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vu1aqp?file=src%2Findex.js

Answer (score 1):

### Some code pattern changes I guess?

I always try to keep using only variables declared with [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) when coding with this stack/architecture, since my goal is to keep data and state immutable.

I also changed the way you call React hooks like `useState`, it keeps the code cleaner and you lose the outdated class-y component inheritance pattern on modern js.

Take a look how everything still works and you prevent rewriting data/state later on

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-elbtq9?file=src%2FApp.js